# pm2 to start and keep alive npm run watch for Laravel's Vue?

Tags: laravel, npm, pm2

How to use pm2 to start and keep alive npm run watch for Laravel's Vue?

I need to use pm2 for keep npm run watch on a shared hosting with ssh login.

How to?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you using NPM and start with `npm start`, try this command:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```